# What are the available bonuses in the extras menu?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

In the main menu, there is an "Extras" menu. The only bonus I have unlocked is the one for having Final Fantasy XIII save data.

What are the rest of the bonuses and how do you unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like *Final Fantasy XIII*, extras are unlockables you can use out-of-game when you complete certain objectives. They're always tied to major achievements, like completing the storyline or non-trivial achievements (gold or platinum trophies in the PS3 version)<sup>1</sup>.

- For the PS3 version, the extras available are XMB themes.
- For the XBox 360 version, the extras available are gamer pictures/icons.

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>: GameFAQs [has the specific info](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/619315-final-fantasy-xiii-2/cheats) about how to unlock them.